# VSTS vNext build "Deploy TestAgent" task never finish when Interactive Process is checked

Tags: automated-tests, vnext

I am using TFS team service to deploy test agent to on premise Windows 2012 server VM in order to run CodedUI test there. When I uncheck Interactive process, it was deployed fine, but when interactive is checked, the task hangs and never finish. I am using the same credential with Admin privilege for both build agent and test agent (meaning I used same identity in team service UI in the deploy test agent step, and the build agent is configure on another PC with the same identity). The task stuck at "Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'xxxxx.xxxxx.com:5986' is taking time. Please Wait". I did a lot of search and did not find solution, please if anybody can help.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the agent version you should install management framework for the right powershell version

also a winrm qucikconfig afterwards can fix it

Comment: I am using agent for Visual Studio 2015, WMF and PS are both 5.0 and WinRM is configured as well. the download and deploy agent steps worked just fine,but it stuck at ConfigureAent.